# jquery sortable without li

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I'd like to vertically reorder divs and sections
I've used jquery sortable before but it does not work with a section tag, is it possible?
Can you give an example please?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

It works fine with sections.

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/manishie/jAXCc/1/

HTML:

```
<section id="sortable">
    <div id="entry1">Apple</div>
    <div id="entry2">Orange</div>
    <div id="entr3y3">Pear</div>
</section>​
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#sortable').sortable();
});
```

​

Comment: You don't need to use any special content. You can just set sortable on the parent; any children to that parent become sortable (e.g. make divs inside a table cell sortable by setting the cell to sortable)